# Python setup.py install throwing zipimport.ZipImportError

Tags: python, django, command-line, command-line-interface, python-2.6

I run the following command in terminal `sudo python2.6 setup.py install` and after some output I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 16, in <module>
    packages=find_packages()
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 76, in run
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 104, in do_egg_install
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 427, in easy_install
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 478, in install_item
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 519, in process_distribution
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 570, in resolve
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2149, in requires
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2141, in _dep_map
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2560, in split_sections
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1854, in yield_lines
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2163, in _get_metadata
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1181, in get_metadata_lines
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1178, in get_metadata
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1238, in _get
zipimport.ZipImportError: bad local file header in /opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/businesscommon-5.63-py2.6.egg
```

I ran the command `unzip -t /opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/businesscommon-5.63-py2.6.egg` to see if the EGG file is a valid ZIP file and it returned 'No errors detected'.

I've done some research on `zipimport.ZipImportError` but can't seem to figure how really to debug or fix it. I don't have much experience with Python so any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all I needed to do was run `sudo python2.5 setup.py install` instead of `sudo python2.6 setup.py install`

Notice that I was oringally using `python2.6` instead of `python2.5`.